# How to transform an outcome which censored from both sides?

Tags: r, data-transformation

I'm trying to fit a `tobit` model for a response outcome where both sides were censored and the distribution is heavily skewed, even for the none-censored observations. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-10:100
a<-rnorm(length(x), sd=5)
b<-(x+a)^(-1/1.5)
y<-c(rep(min(b), 20),b,rep(max(b),100))
hist(y)
```

To fit a `tobit` model, `y` is assumed to be normal distributed. My question is how to transform this `y` so as to be normal-like distributed. I believe the below model is incorrect without a proper transformation of `y`.

```
age<-abs(as.integer(50+rnorm(length(y), sd=2)))
require(censReg)
fit<-censReg(y~age, left=min(y), right=max(y))
summary(fit)
```